# Collectionview in a TableView - How to select item?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have made a `CollectionView` in a `TableView` for vertical and horizontal scrolling and customisable cells. This works so far. The problem is: I can't select an item of the `CollectionView`. I think the problem could be something with the delegate outlets but I could't find a solution.

I'm pretty new with Swift, so maybe I overlook something obvious.

My `TableViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class HomeVTwoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var headers = ["Live", "Friends", "Last commented"]

    @IBAction func cancelBtnPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return headers[section]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){

        view.tintColor = UIColor.black
        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        if section == 0 {
            header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
            view.tintColor = UIColor.white
        }
        else {
            view.tintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return headers.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellBig", for: indexPath) as! HomeVTwoTableViewCell

            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSmall", for: indexPath) as! HomeVTwoTableViewCellSmall

            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSmall", for: indexPath) as! HomeVTwoTableViewCellSmall

            return cell
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 225.0
        }
        else {
            return 120.0
        }
    }
}
```

My `TableViewCell` with the `CollectionView`:

```
import UIKit

class HomeVTwoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    fileprivate var images = [UIImage]()
    {
        didSet
        {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func setup(for images: [UIImage])
    {
        self.images = images
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return communityName.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return communityName.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelect")
        selectedCommunity = communityId[indexPath.row]
        let home = HomeViewController()
        home.showCommunityDetail()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        guard let cell =   collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCellBig", for: indexPath) as? HomeVTwoCollectionViewCell else
        {
            fatalError("Cell has wrong type")
        }

       //cell.imageView.image = image
       cell.titleLbl.text = communityName[indexPath.row]
       cell.imageView.downloadedFrom(link :"deleted because privat")

       return cell
    }
}
```

My `CollectionViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class HomeVTwoCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Did you connect delegate with collectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set delegate and dataSource like this

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate   = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this line. Just add, it will work fine collectionView.delegate = self

Comment: I am talking about collectionView.

Comment: @Lukas you have not given me the green check as I am the first one who give answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

You have not confirm delegate of collection view.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate   = self
}
```

Comment: I have not said to confirm tableview delegate, I have said to confirm collectionview delegate.